# (COVID) How to request fine reduction? (USA-NJ)

Tags: united-states, rent, covid-19, new-jersey

I have been renting a unit with Newport Management, Jersey City since August 2020 and have been on time with my rent for the past 11 months. For the last 6 months I am unemployed and have no income, yet have managed to keep up on my rents and utilities. However, I was late on 30% of the total rent by 4 days in June, and the landlord has fined with a 5% late fee on the total rent, is it somehow possible to request a reduction of the fine?

Any rule or law signed by governor/mayor would definitely give a strong foundation. There was an order signed by the governor it can be found on this link: [Governor order](https://www.nj.gov/governor/news/news/562020/20200424c.shtml)

Is there anything that I can use to get that late fee eliminated?

Comment: Could you expand on why do you believe that you should be excused from paying the late fee (which you agreed to when you signed the lease)? Have you discussed the issues you're having with your landlord? I think it's unlikely that your landlord's mortgage company waives late fees when he's late paying the mortgage on the unit you're living in ...

Comment: How can you be late on 40% of the rent?  Did you pay a portion on time, and a portion late?

Comment: I am an international student with access to no money, have been unemployed for the last 7 months, I am living on borrowed money and have paid the rent of last 11 months on time, do you think this calls for a pass just one time and that too on only part of the rent that was late? @brhans, maybe showing humanity and understanding how covid is difficult for millions of people?

Comment: Yes, I paid 70% of the rent on time and the rest 30% was late by 4 days @RonJohn

Comment: Ok - so *Have you discussed the issues you're having with your landlord?* Chances are he's just a guy trying to get by too.

Comment: I did request them a lot, but they said we won't redact it. it is my first time paying the rent late, and that too a small portion, I don't know how else to plead my case

Comment: If you don't have access to money you aren't allowed to rent a home. Sad but true.

Answer (score 3):

According to your link, you can direct the landlord to apply your security deposit to your rent.

You could pay the 5% fine for this month, and also instruct the landlord to apply your security deposit to next month's rent, pursuant to the New Jersey order. Then pay on time next month, if any amount remains due.